# Outlook office.js add-in task pane closing issue on Outlook for Mac

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-for-mac

We have a Outlook add-in using add-in commands. We have a task pane with user info that includes a simple hyperlink with target set to "_blank". When the user clicks on this link a web page pops up. If the user subsequently closes Outlook, everything closes down fine on PC Desktop Outlook and OWA.

On Outlook for Mac however there is a problem. In that case when you close Outlook everything goes away, but our task pane stays on the screen like it is stuck. If you click on this task pane Outlook reappears but the inbox is blank, and only the task pane and the current email is showing. You must manually close the task pane and then Outlook for everything to close properly.

A few observations:

1. This only occurs for the main mail read command surface. If you pop open an email and open the task pane from the email's Ribbon, and click the link from there, the email closes fine.
2. If you open the task pane from the main mail read command surface but you do not click on the link on the task pane, then Outlook closes without issue.

It is like the task pane is holding on to a reference to the child window pop up, so Outlook for Mac cannot properly close the task pane.

Can anyone else reproduce this issue? Is opening a child window from a task pane not allowed, or is there something extra you must do to make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not seen this issue, it would be helpful if you can share some more info on this 
- OS version 
- Outlook version 
- Manifest file used

Comment: Microsoft Outlook for Mac 15.35 (170610), macOS Sierra Version 10.12.5. What are you looking for in the manifest? At this point I am not allowed to share it, but I can mockup pieces. @anil the task pane in question is a simple one with static text and a link. Are you saying that you cannot reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Carbo, I was not able to repro this issue on my machine. I had tested with target set to "_blank". Is this issue happening on all Mac machines ?

Comment: Yes, all Mac machines but I will try more machines when I can to be sure. One important note: I discovered that you need to close the pop-up window before you close Outlook to get this to happen.